# Помогите с AJAX запросом на сервер

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуйте... Помогите пожалуйста. Значит смысл в том, что в JS есть переменная, в которой текст, и он должен отправиться, к примеру, на `php.php`, в котором есть скрипт:

```
if(isset($_GET['mail'])){  
    $mail = $_GET['mail'];  
    if($mail == 'test@test.ru'){  
        echo "no";  
    }else{  
        echo "yes";  
    }  
}
```

И в зависимости от полученного результат, в переменную JS должен знакинуться текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключаешь jquery. Далее:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.send_email').click(function(){
       //допустим ваша js переменная с e-mail называется mail
       $.get('php.php?mail='+mail,function(res){
            $('#mail_result').html(res);
            if (res=='ok'){
               var mail_res=true;
            } else { var mail_res=false; }

       });

   });
});
```

#mail_result - какой нить div или span или что захочешь с указанным id

.send_email  - ссылка, кнопка, все что угодно с указанным классом, отправляет запрос

Answer (score 1):

если у вас подключена JQuery то просто передайте параметр вот так

```
 $.get('php.php',{mail:'текст'},function(dates){
    alert (dates);
    // выпишет то что вернет пхп обработав переменную
    });
```

Comment: получается в "dates" будет значение из пхп?

Comment: dates - это я просто так назвал переменную. Да, в ней будет то что вы выпишите в ПХП

Comment: не могли переделать пхп код.. что-то я не въежаю((

Comment: а пхп и ненудо переделывать. надо просто подключить яваскриптовскую ну например с моего сайта
<pre><code><script type="text/javascript" src="http://grimon.net/js/jquery.js"></script></code></pre>

Comment: не работает

Comment: а вот тут надо код. что такое check и откуда оно берется вообще. и ставьте < pre >< code > код < /code></ pre > (без пробелов) когда код пишите

Comment: может проще?
<pre><code>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://grimon.net/js/jquery.js"></script>
elem = document.preview.mail.value;
if (elem == "") checkError('mail', dutyField + title);
else if (!mail(elem)) checkError('mail', wrongField + title);
else{ $.get('email-login.php',{mail:elem},function(dates){
alert (dates);
});
}
</code></pre>

Comment: **Grimon**, и сколько же вы данных сможете передать методом GET? :D

Тут исходя из названия переменной надо использовать .post

Answer (score 1):

Вот тебе один из js кодов где-то в книге когда-то выдрал он отправляет фоновый запрос при нажатие на кнопку происходит process() :

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();  
function createXmlHttpRequestObject()  
{

  var xmlHttp;

  if(window.ActiveXObject) 
  { 
    try 
    { 
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 
    catch (e)  
    { 
      xmlHttp = false; 
    } 
  } 
  // if running Mozilla or other browsers 
  else 
  { 
    try  
    { 
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    catch (e)  
    { 
      xmlHttp = false; 
    } 
  } 
  // return the created object or display an error message 
  if (!xmlHttp) 
      alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object."); 
  else  
    return xmlHttp; 
}

// make asynchronous HTTP request using the XMLHttpRequest object  
function process() 
{

  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0) 
  { 
    // в переменую name вставляю значение тут вы можете вставить любое свое значение
    mail = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("mail").value); 
    // execute the quickstart.php page from the server

    xmlHttp.open("GET", "php.php?mail=" + mail, true);   
    // define the method to handle server responses 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse; 
    // make the server request 
    xmlHttp.send(null); 
  } 
  else 
    setTimeout('process()', 1000); 
} 
function handleServerResponse()  
{ 
   if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)  
  { 
    // status of 200 indicates the transaction completed successfully 
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200)  
    { 
      xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML; 
      xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement; 
      Respn = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data; 
      document.getElementById("Ans").innerHTML =  Respn;
    }  
    else  
    { 
      alert("There was a problem accessing the server: " + xmlHttp.statusText); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Если, что-то не понятно скажи разъясню....

Comment: ну ты и загнул) ему проще надо

Comment: Проще чем целю библиотеку подключать

Comment: А помоему проще библиотеку подключить и пользоваться ее прелестями, чем новичку взрывать мозг. Ее же не зря придумали, и очень большой % программистов ею пользуются ибо это ускоряет процесс разработки)

Comment: Не отрицаю, но я сторонник самописки =)

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот обьясните мне - зачем подключать jquery для одного ajax запроса?-.-
вообщем сути особо не понял ну собственно вот пример запроса без jquery

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.doSend = function () {
    this.open("GET","/php.php?mail=somemail", true);
    this.send(null);
}
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         alert(this.responseText);
         // в переменной this.responseText лежит ответ скрипта
    }
}
```

ну думаю понятно что данные для отправки можно формировать...

чтобы вызвать запрос с кода, например:

```
    onload = function () {
         request.doSend();
    }
```

на событии:

```
<button onclick="javascript:request.doSend()">Отправить запрос</button>
```

ну и так само можно написать так:

```
    function beforeRequest() {
         //.......... тута чето проверяем делаем и т.д.
         request.doSend();
    }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за то что уделили внимание, но мне не очень понятно, как и что((
Вот к примеру у меня есть html страница
<div id="alert"></div>
<form action=''...>
   <input type="text" name="mail">
   <input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: Ну и php скрипт:  
// перед подключение  
$mail = $_GET['mail'];  
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE mail = '".$mail."'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  $mail_bd = $row['mail'];
 }
if( $mail == @mail_bd){echo 1;}else{echo 2;}

Ну и как соеденить это с JS кодом? Т.е. если такой email зареген выводит 1.. а в JS будет проверка, если вернули "1" то в <div id="alert"> выдать ошибку.. 
Как-то так

Answer (score 0):

[Изучайте](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/) , к сожалению мне пора уходить, код подсказать не могу.

Comment: А когда вы будете?